# Diophantine equation with constraints

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, gcd-and-lcm

Suppose that we have the following:
$aX+bY+cZ=d$

where $X, Y, Z$ are positive integers and

$X+Y+Z \le g$

Does the condition to have $gcd(a,b,c)|d$ (to show a solution exists) still valid in this problem? How to know if we only have a unique solution?

Comment: As is $\gcd(X,Y,Z)\mid d$ but I digress

Comment: Sorry Roddy MacPhee but I did not get your comment.

Answer (score 0):

No, even if $\gcd(a,b,c)\mid d$, a solution might not exist with the extra assumptions on $X,Y,Z$.

Take for example
$$
2X+2Y+2Z=2.
$$
Clearly there is no solution to this that has all of $X,Y,Z$ strictly positive.

Or take
$$
X+Y+Z=100
$$
and $g=5$. This also clearly has no solutions.

So $\gcd(a,b,c)\mid d$ is no longer a sufficient condition, though it is of course still necessary.

To determine whether there is a unique solution, I would parametrise the non-restricted problem using the usual method, and then analyse the result of that. When I have some time to think about it, I might try to find a general sufficient criterion.

Comment: Thanks Milten for your help. This is exactly what I was looking for. Another question, under what condition we could say that the constrained Diophantine equation is not solvable?

Answer (score -1):

Let $e=\gcd(a,b,c)$ .

This means that $a=e\cdot a', b=e \cdot b',c=e \cdot c'$.

But $aX+bY+cZ=d$, so this means that $e\cdot(a'X+b'Y+c'Z)=d$.
So $e$ must divide $d$.

Comment: Dollar signs \prime and \cdot can fix this ...

Comment: Thanks Jean Valj. I am not sure why did you assume that $gcd(a,b,c)=g$ but we have $X+Y+Z \le g$